# "Click again to undo" showing when there's nothing to undo

Tags: bug

I've noticed a small discrepancy between buttons on questions - When you hover your mouse over the downvote button on a question, you see the normal message:

[image: Bug1]

When the downvote button is already clicked, you see the normal message + (click again to undo):

[image: Bug2]

But when you hover over the "mark as favorite question", it already says "click again to undo", even when not already clicked. **This is what I think is bugged**:

[image: Bug3]

Conversely, when you click it and hover over, the message is "click to undo".

[image: Bug4]

It's very minor, but shouldn't there be some unison between all the button descriptions? I don't think the star should say "click again to undo" if it hasn't been clicked already.

Comment: Huh!  I never even noticed that!

Comment: The text makes sense. It says "click *again* to undo" meaning "click a second time to un-favorite the post".

Comment: @BSMP:  The inconsistency is when it's displayed.  The OP demonstrates that it appears over the other vote tooltips only when an action has been taken, but with favorites, it appears all the time.

Comment: @BSMP Sorry, as Makoto stated, it's *when* the message is showing up. For the downvote button it only shows up when the button's been clicked, but for the star it shows up when not-clicked, and then once again after it has been clicked. Just strange.

Comment: @Makoto Indeed. Apologies dwirony. Now I'm wondering if "click again to undo" is still in the tooltip for voting if your vote is locked. (Just checked: it does, so the difference isn't down to undoing a vote being time limited.)

Comment: @Makoto Might you be able to edit my question from "Click to undo" to "Click again to undo"?

Comment: Seems strange that you couldn't do that yourself @dwirony, but I've done it.

Comment: MSE dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250830/favourite-button-tooltip-is-incorrect/250831#250831

Comment: I think @dwirony is correct .. the behavior should be same for both as both working in a similar way (like toggle).